# BeforeShowDay doesn't changed in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a function to disabled specific days before show date in `datepicker`, but I have an error: when I call my function in first time it works, but in second call I still have the first result.
For example on the first call I have Sunday disabled, when I call the function again I have Sunday disabled too.
I see that the error is in the variable used in `BeforShowDay`, is still not changed just inside `datepicker`, but outside is changer in each call.

This is my code:

```
function loadFreeDays (etablissement) {
  var array=[];
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/promo3/etablissments/getFreeDays/"+etablissement,
    data:  {'etablissement': etablissement } ,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      $.each(response, function(i, value) {
        array.push(value);
      }),  

      /*console.log(" diasbled days are "+array); here variable still is changed  */ 

      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
          /* here array variable still not changed */
          for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (date.getDay() == array[i][0]) {
              return [false];
            }
          }
          var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date); 
          var day = date.getDay(); 
          return [true, '']; 
        }
      });

    },
    error: function(x, e) { }
  });
}
```

Comment: aren't you getting an error for that `,` before your commented `console.log`?

Comment: No I got no errror

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by colling `$('#txtDate').datepicker("destroy");` before ajax function.
It work now.